# Расширение ключевого слова readonly на все члены класса. В чем смысл?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

В общем, в 8.0 версии языка нам [разрешат](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1710) вешать readonly даже на методы.

Какой в этом практический смысл? Сходу, не могу придумать когда это могло бы пригодится, ведь можно делать ридонли свойства.

Comment: Там же по ссылке есть раздел motivation - это и есть "зачем это нужно"

Comment: @PashaPash ну, как я понимаю, мотивация в том, что бы дать понять пользователю объекта то, что вызывая определенный метод он не изменит состояние объекта. Правда, а интересна ли данная дополнительная информация конечному пользователю класса? Да и название методов обычно всегда говорит само за себя о том, будет ли меняться объект или нет.

Comment: Там в разделе motivation есть конкретные примеры, когда эта информация интереса конечному пользователю класса (возможность избегать копирования структур при in параметрах и т.д.).